# Как передать интерполяционные переменные?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Строится цикл:

```
for ($counte = 1; $counte <= 4; $counte++) {
  $iden += 1;
  print "<input type='text' name='create_input{$iden}' maxlength='30' />";
}
```

После выполнения цикла создаются 4 input'a с именами create_input1 до 4;
Задача состоит в том, чтобы передать эти инпуты с таким идентификатором в другой обработчик. Но они вот именно что не передаются. Незнаю возможно ли такое вообще, если да то помогите реализовать. Можно и другими способами сделать все это, но хочется знать можно ли так передать, т.е 2 переменные в одном идентификаторе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы практически догадались как решить эту задачу, но немного промахнулись в своих размышлениях. Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно передать массив параметров. Собственно все что нужно - добавить к name атрибуту формы `[]`, собственно все. Т.е.:

```
for ($counte = 1; $counte <= 4; $counte++) {
  echo '<input type="text" name="create_input[]" maxlength="30" />';
}
```

Что-бы получить данные:

```
 $postData = $_POST['create_input'];
 // is_array( $postData ); // -> true
 foreach( $postData as $chunk ) {
     echo $chunk;
 }
```

Для общей информации - массив параметров, так-же, можно передавать и гет запросом, т.е. например есть скрипт:

```
print_r( $_GET );
```

Ну и, например - передаем следующие параметры

```
http://pathToLolScript.php?a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4
```

Получаем ответ вида:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

Собственно именно в таком формате и отправляются POST данные формы, если добавить пару квадратных скобок в name атрибуте.

Если же я вас таки неверно понял и вы просто хотитесь пройти по всем пришедшим POST данным, то `foreach` в помощь:

```
foreach( $_POST as $postKey => $value ) {
  // $postKey - ключи
  // $value - их значения
  // $_POST[$postKey] === $value 
}
```

Comment: Это то все хорошо, но мне нужно передать не значения внутри инпутов, а имена самих инпутов, т.е create_input1 до 4 в другой обработчик. А же их сделал следующим образом: создал переменную ident += 1 и пристыковал ее к create_input,или как это называется произвел интерполяцию переменных. Дословно получилось как create_input{$ident}. На выходе получается createinput1...4 так как цикл крутится 4 раза)

Comment: Т.е. вам нужен массив name атрибутов что-ли?

Если да, то:

    $keys = array_keys($_POST);
    // $keys - массив значений name атрибутов

Кстати в foreach цикле тоже, как-бы, проход по ключам